# Set COLUMN inverse search for Okular and Sublime Text

Tags: sublime-text, okular

I'm using Okular to do the inverse searching.
In the Okular setting, my command is

```
subl %f:%l:%c
```

I also installed Sublime Text 3 and the LaTeXTools package.

However, when I do the inverse search in Okular (by `shift + left click`), the cursor in Sublime Text is placed at the beginning of the expected line `%l`, not the expected column `%c`. In other words, it succeeds in reaching the expected line, but not the expected column.

Please show me how to reach the expected column.
Thank you for your help.